# How to use grunt-contrib-concat with remote files?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-copy

I am new to Grunt and I am creating my first build / deploy task.  I currently can use grunt to concat and uglify local CSS and JS resources, but I can't seem to find a way to get this to work with remote resources (either over the internet or on our internal network).

Is this possible, or do I need to create a separate task to download these resources locally before I run the concat task?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364948/grunt-concat-files-on-a-different-domain-or-on-different-server