# Grunt concat files on a different domain or on different server

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

***Edit working version and explanation***

I want to concat files from different server into my destination folder using grunt, and grunt-concat and with something like that:

```
  concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['dev.staticcontent.com/media/clientcontent/library/*.js', 'js/*.js'],       
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
```

each time I tried, I received no error from grunt, but my `dist/marketing-home.js` file is empty... Like it didn't find anything.

Console:

```
C:\Project\My>grunt 
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File dist/marketing-home.js created.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task

Done, without errors.
```

**New Version**

After the help of Kris, I was able to do it without passing through the web using `grunt-exec` and doing using `COPY` or `XCOPY` shell command.

ex.

```
   exec: {
     copy : {
        cmd: function () {
               var path = "\\\\dev-server123\\WebSites\\Static_Contents\\Media\\clientcontent";
               return "copy dist\\*.min.js " + path + " /y";
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: The `src` path is either incorrect or not accessible to the GruntFile. I am not positive if absolute paths work or not, but I would think they would. Everything else appears to be correct. Is this `dev.staticcontent.com/media/clientcontent/library/` the absolute path?

Comment: no it's not an absolute path it's a URL 
example :http://dev.staticcontent.com/media/clientcontent/library/calendar.js ( just an example not working)

Comment: I also tried absolute paths, and it didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried a relative path just to test out your GruntFile? Maybe just create a test directory in the same directory as your GruntFile.. and point to that. If that works then it is probably the path. If it doesn't then probably something in the GruntFile that is incorrect.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Yeah I did try using a path in my current project ( `'js/*.js'`) and it did work. I know it's related to the path. I want to know if there is a way to add a file from a different domain. I'm not able to make it work. If you can show me how to include google jquery cdn into my gruntfile( `src: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js']`, it will be the same for my other private files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like concat task handles absolute paths or files from remote locations. However I was able to get it to work using curl task combined with the concat task.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    curl: {
      'download/jquery.js': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js',
    },
    concat: {
        js: {
            src: ['download/jquery.js'],
            dest: 'output/test.js'
        },
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-curl');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['curl', 'concat']);
};
```

**DEMO DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:**
[image]

I used this Node Module Package for CURL. https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-curl, there may be better ones out there. But this one seemed to work fine.

Comment: Cool it did work! too bad I have to pass through the internet instead of directly from my server. anyway thx a lot!

Comment: That is good to know. But if the files being concatenated have the same root or parent as your GruntFile then you should be able to use relative paths and not have to use the CURL task. And I think even if they are on the same server but under different directories (ie, gruntFile's parent's sibling) you could use relative paths. But it might also depend on how your permissions are set up.