# Can grunt-copy copy a remote file from a server?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

Is there a grunt task that can pull down or copy a file from a remote server into your local build?

Comment: For anyone else looking I found this answer using grunt-curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364948/grunt-concat-files-on-a-different-domain-or-on-different-server

Answer (score 1):

Grunt-contrib-copy is designed for copying files within a local filesystem, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) there's no references to doing remote server transactions.

So unless the remote server is mounted to your local filesystem, the answer is probably not.  There's other plugins that should be able to provide this need though.